# MySQL upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6, date null condition failing

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5, mysqlupgrade

We have migrated our MySQL database from v5.5 to 5.6, all was working good,
but today I have got one issue that column which having null value failing the condition.
**condition:** (order_schedule.date_from and order_schedule.date_to both are null in database)

order_schedule.date_from IS NULL AND order_schedule.date_to IS NULL

this should be true while its returning false after upgrade MySQL 5.6, checked same is returning true in MySQL5.5.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This condition will return true in v5.6 as well, if both fields are truly set to null. So, my guess is that at least one of the columns is set to some other value.

Comment: select count(*) from mybooking_testing.testtable where NOW() NOT BETWEEN testtable.orderDateFrom AND testtable.orderDateTO
and testtable.id = 176544

returning 1 in MySQL5.5 while 0 in MySQL 5.6. @Shadow

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not tell us anything because we do not know what your data looks like.

Comment: @Shadow this is the create statement and only one row in testtable ie: id =176544 and orderDateFrom =NULL orderDateTO =NULL
  'CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderDateFrom` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderDateTO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;'

Comment: Great. If you run the query with the selection criteria mentioned in the question itself (`order_schedule.date_from IS NULL AND order_schedule.date_to IS NULL`), then is there any difference between the 2 MySQL instances?

Comment: @Shadow No difference both return same, only difference when use NOT BETWEEN order_schedule.date_from AND order_schedule.date_to old version 5.5 return 1 row while new v5.6 returns 0 row.

Comment: Then pls update your question because at the moment it is incorrect.

Comment: To be honest, the result of the query from v5.6 is the one I would expect from the not between clause, since null values can only be compared using the `is [not] null` operator. I did not find any evidence of MySQL changing the behaviour of its comparison operators from v5.5. At the moment I'm a bit sceptical about the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Just change credentials for that colomn and allow null

Comment: select count(*) from mybooking_testing.testtable where NOW() NOT BETWEEN testtable.orderDateFrom AND testtable.orderDateTO
and testtable.id = 176544

returning 1 in MySQL5.5 while 0 in MySQL 5.6. @aftabHafeez